# Is it possible to force a credential check every time a network share is opened in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, passwords, credentials, share-credentials

I am running Windows 7 Ultimate and I have mapped a network share to a drive letter. The first time that I open the share, I am prompted for login credentials as expected. I do not select the "Remember my credentials" checkbox and can login successfully, but every time that I re-open the share during the session, I do not need to re-enter my credentials.

Is there any way to force a credential check every time that I re-open the share? I do not want to perform a reboot every time that I want to "re-lock" the share.

Comment: I also tried right clicking on the mounted share after authenticating and select disconnect. The icon changes to show a big red X but then when I try to reconnect to the share, I get an error message that tells me `X:\ refers to a location that is unavailable...`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that there is necessarily a way to do this automatically. That may yield unexpected results each time you browse a folder or try to copy one (or multiple) files. However, you can look to see which network shares you have accessed and remove if needed.

I can see this valuable if you need to move away from your computer and do not wish to reboot to clear the sessions and/or if someone may hop onto your computer and you do not want them getting fancy with browsing your network and seeing a share with credentials already entered.

You can open a command prompt: `Start > Run > CMD`

Type `rundll32.exe keymgr.dll, KRShowKeyMgr`

From here you can remove authenticated network shares so that the next time you will have to type in the credentials again. I know that this isn't exactly what you're looking for, but may be an alternative.

[image]

Comment: Because I am not clicking on the checkbox to save the credentials, the server does not show up in the Stored User Names and Passwords list.

Comment: This just saved approximately two days of my nerves with clean Windows 7 installation not asking me username/password when trying to connect to already shared (and before re-install accessible) stuff on different computer in the same workgroup. Thank you, good sir.

Answer (score 1):

Fire up a command prompt and do a `net use`.  You will probably see a connection open the share and system you are connected to.  Run `net use \\server\share /delete` to disconnect.  You might also see a connection like `\\server\ipc$` connected.  You will need to close that as well.  Once you completely close your connections, you should be re-prompted unless you saved your password.

You could put this in a batch file as well.

Another thing you could do is simply logout/login again.  It should be faster then a full reboot.

Comment: When I attempt to run the command `net use \\server\share /delete` (substituting my information) I receive the message `The network connection could not be found. More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2250.` and the network share is not removed from the `net use` list.